# Relationship between vectors in convex quadrilateral

Tags: vectors

> We have the triangle $ABC$. $M$ is the center of the line segment $BC$. $D$ is a point in the triangle's plane so that $ABDC$ is a convex quadrilateral. $N$ is center of the line segment $AD$.
>
> Calculate $\vec {AC}+\vec {DB}$  in relation to  $\vec{MN}$

How to solve this problem and these kind of problems in general? Easier ones I just do by writing down all the vectors that I need and then finding a relation between them. But what would be the steps I should always take in solving these?

Edit: Here's how I imagine the whole thing looks:

[image]

Comment: what is $N$ ???

Comment: Ugh, sorry @Surb , missed that. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\vec {AM} = \frac12(\vec {AB}+\vec{AC})$$ and
$$\vec {AN} = \frac12\vec {AD}.$$
Now consider the fact that $\vec {MN} = \vec {AN} - \vec {AM}$
and see where that leads you.

There are several other ways to approach this, but a good first step is
to write down vector equations that represent the statements
"$M$ is the midpoint of the line segment $BC$" and
"$N$ is the midpoint of the line segment $AD$,"
as the first two equations above do.
(The first equations in mathlove's neatly symmetric answer
are also expressions of these two statements.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I managed to find an answer, and it's the same as the other answer I got on here, so chances are it's right!

Answer (score 2):

Using $\vec{MB}+\vec{MC}=\vec{NA}+\vec{ND}=\vec{0}$, we have

$$\begin{align}\vec{AC}+\vec{DB}&=\vec{MC}-\vec{MA}+\vec{MB}-\vec{MD}\\&=\vec{MC}-(\vec{NA}-\vec{NM})+\vec{MB}-(\vec{ND}-\vec{NM})\\&=\vec{MC}+\vec{MB}-(\vec{NA}+\vec{ND})+2\vec{NM}\\&=-2\vec{MN}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for providing me with an answer! I could check myself after I managed to solve the problem.